# Creating new columns using a for loop

Tags: r

I am new to R (Economist with background in Stata) and I am having trouble getting a nested for loop to work for me. I know the issue is that I don't have a good understanding of how to use the loop counter as part of a variable name.

A bit of background. I have data frame with data on average rental rates for homes of different size (1 bedroom, 2 bedroom, etc) and data on annual earnings (mean, median, and various percentiles). I am trying to generate a series of new columns containing the ratio of these two things (rental rate / mean earnings).

Specifically my variables are:

- `beds1, beds2, beds3, beds4`
- `mean, median, p10, p25, p75, p90`

So you see I need to generate 24 new columns of cost/earnings data. I could write out 24 lines of code but I don't want to. More importantly, I want to learn an efficient way of doing this in R. In Stata I could do this very simply using a nested for loop, but I can't get it to work in R. Here is my code so far.

```
for (i in 1:4) {
    stat <- c("median", "mean", "p10", "p25", "p75","p90")
    for (x in stat) {
        df$beds[i]_[x] <- round((df$beds[i]/df$[x]),digits=3)
    }
}
```

When I run this code the error I get is

```
Error: unexpected input in:
"    for (x in stat) {
    df$beds[i]_"
>     }
Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

I have tried to use the double brackets `[[]]` but that didn't change the results. If anyone has some insight into why the dynamic variables names aren't working please let me know. Even better, since I guess loops are evil in R, if anyone knows a way to use `lapply` to get this done, I would love to hear that too.

---

EDIT

Thanks @Spacedman for the comment. I think I am getting what you're saying. So does that mean that there simply isn't anyway to do what I want to do in R?

```
var1 <- c("beds1", "beds2")
var2 <- c("mean", "median")

for (i in 1:2) {
    for (j in 1:2) {
        df$var1[i]_var2[j] <- df$var1[i]/df$var2[j]
    }
}
```

I think this should grab the elements of the lists `var1` and `var2` so that  when `i=1` and `j=1`, `df$var1[i]/df$var2[j]` should mean `df$beds1/df$mean`. Or would R get mad and think I was trying to divide strings?

---

FINAL EDIT WITH ANSWER FROM @SPACEEMAN

Thanks @Spacedman. I loved your spoiler and thank you for providing additional help. I didn't fully grasp the difference between the two ways of referring to columns after your last post, but I think I have a better idea now. I did a bit of tweaking and now I have something that works perfectly. Thanks again!

```
beds <- c("beds1", "beds2", "beds3", "beds4")
stat <- c("median", "mean", "p10", "p25", "p75","p90")

for(i in beds){
    for(x in stat){
        res = paste0(i,"_",x)
        df[[res]]=round(df[[i]]/df[[x]],digits=3)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is not a macro expansion language like other languages you might be used to.

`x[i]`, if `i=123`, does not "expand" into `x123`. It gets the value of the 123rd element of the vector, `x`.

So `df$beds[i]` tries to get the i'th element of a vector `df$beds`.

You need to know two things:

1. How to construct strings from other strings.

For this you can use `paste0`:

```
> for(i in 1:4){
+  print(paste0("beds",i))
+ }
[1] "beds1"
[1] "beds2"
[1] "beds3"
[1] "beds4"
```

2. How to access columns by names.

For this you can use double square brackets. In a list:

```
> z = list()
> n = "thing"
```

Double squabs evaluate their index and use that. So:

```
> z[[n]] = 99
```

Will set `z$thing`, but dollar sign indexing is literal, so:

```
> z$n = 123
```

will set `z$n`:

```
> z
$thing
[1] 99

$n
[1] 123
```

hopefully that's enough hints to get you through. It should all be covered in basic R tutorials online.

## Spoiler

If you want to work out how to do it yourself, look away now...

First, lets create a sample data frame - you should include something like this in your question so we have common test data to work on. I'll just have three beds and two stats:

```
> df = data.frame(
     beds1=c(1,2,3),
     beds2=c(5,2,3),
     beds3=c(6,6,6),
     mean=c(8,4,3),
     median=c(1,7,4))
> df
      beds1 beds2 beds3 mean median
    1     1     5     6    8      1
    2     2     2     6    4      7
    3     3     3     6    3      4
```

Now the work. We loop over the bed number and the character stats. The bed column name is stored in `bed` by pasting "beds" to the number `i`. We compute the name of the result column (`res`) for a given bed number and stat by pasting `"beds"` to `i` and `"_"` and the name of the stat in `x`.

Then set the new resulting column to the value by dividing the beds number by the stat. We use `[[z]]` to get the columns by name:

```
> for(i in 1:3){
  stats=c("mean","median")
  for(x in stats){
    bed = paste0("beds",i)
    res = paste0("beds",i,"_",x)
    df[[res]]=round(df[[bed]]/df[[x]],digits=3)
  }
 }
```

Resulting in....

```
> df
  beds1 beds2 beds3 mean median beds1_mean beds1_median beds2_mean beds2_median
1     1     5     6    8      1      0.125        1.000      0.625        5.000
2     2     2     6    4      7      0.500        0.286      0.500        0.286
3     3     3     6    3      4      1.000        0.750      1.000        0.750
  beds3_mean beds3_median
1       0.75        6.000
2       1.50        0.857
3       2.00        1.500
>
```

Comment: Edit. moved comment to the question because the formatting didn't work.